# Queuing discord.js bot commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My bot manages server auctions, so order of commands(bids specifically) is quite important.

The commands do things like requests and DB updates during execution, and I've noticed that if I run two commands at the exact same time they run in 'parallel'(javascript parallel). This can cause some issues during validation(eg. bid price > current highest).

Is there a way to block the thread to complete a command before serving another?

I'm using the approach from the discord.js guide

`index.js`

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}
```

`commands/command.js`

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('<name>')
        .setDescription('<desc>'),
    async execute(interaction) {

        // code, await db calls, etc

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a lock on the command execution body using the [async-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-lock) npm package.

`lock.js`

```
const AsyncLock = require('async-lock');

let lock = new AsyncLock();

module.exports = lock
```

`commands/command.js`

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const lock = require('../lock');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('<name>')
        .setDescription('<desc>'),
    async execute(interaction) {

        lock.acquire("", async (done) => {
            try {
                // code, await db calls, etc
            catch {
                // errors
            } finally {
                done();
            }
        }, () => {});
    }
}
```

Feedback welcome!